# Grammar of "It is rarely that + (clause)"

Tags: grammar

The following question is motivated by [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20841/4559) at ELL. Here, I'm not interested in the correctness (that's already been answered at ELL) but in the possibility of interpreting this construction as an *it-cleft*.

**Clefting** is a construction by which a single sentence is broken up into two clauses so that the clause moved to the front receives more emphasis.

For example, given the sentence:

> Police rarely arrest people without adequate suspicion.

Imagine that we want to emphasize *people without adequate suspicion*, then we would write:

> It is **people without adequate suspicion** that police rarely arrest.

The question I want to ask is whether I can use an *it-cleft* to emphasize an adverb. In the sample sentence, imagine that we want to emphasize how *rarely* this happens, then we would write:

> It is **rarely** that police arrest people without adequate suspicion.

Comment: Yes you can but it sounds very tortuous and unnatural. The best English is usually the most straightforward and concise.

Comment: I can't cite an authoritative reference, but I can opine that this particular example sounds odd. One would typically expect "rare" rather than "rarely" here. On the other hand, "It is only rarely that…" sounds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question I want to ask is whether I can use an it-cleft to emphasize an adverb.

The 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, has this info for when the foregrounded element is an adverb phrase--on page 1419:

> (e) AdvPs
>
> [16]
>
> - i. *It was* ***only gradually*** *that I came to realize how much I was being exploited.*
> - ii. *She learns sex is something sordid, [and when she experiences it for the first time herself it is* ***incoherently, clumsily, but half shyly and half inquisitively***].
> - iii. *It isn't* ***often*** *they're as late as this.*
>
> Example [ii] here is truncated, with omission of the relative clause *that she experiences it*.

If you want more info, I could look into the 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for some reassurance this interpretation wasn't something crazy. Your answer gives me this. (We are usually advised not to grant an answer straight away, so I will wait before I do.)

Comment: I doubt this is the whole story, though. As other answers in the ELL question show, it-clefting with adverbs like _rarely_ simply are not used. The overt adverbs cited here are all adverbs that describe manner and thus very clearly modify the verb itself, while _rarely_ is more of a sentential marker—its scope is bigger than just the verb, like _often_. For such markers, it-clefting seems to prefer switching to adjectival forms if the adverb is transparently formed.

Comment: How about "Only rarely do police arrest people without adequate suspicion."? Wouldn't this cleft sentence be more usual?

Comment: @user58319 Your example *""Only rarely do police arrest people without adequate suspicion."* isn't a cleft construction, as it is a main clause headed by the verb "arrest". A cleft construction involves a main clause headed by a form of the verb "BE".

Comment: @F.E.Right you are! What then is this type of 'detachment', of 'mise en évidence' called in English grammar?

Comment: @user58319 Are you referring to your example: "***Only rarely*** do police arrest people without adequate suspicion."? Where the "Only rarely" phrase is fronted (and which then also causes subject-aux inversion)? If so, then: *Although "only" is not a marker of negation, it does have a close connection with negation. That connection is so close that subject-auxiliary inversion is obligatory in constructions with an initial "only".* (from an older post of mine on another grammar forum)